# Using PHP $_GET to Insert data to DB

Tags: php

I'm using `$_GET['id']` for said task. I'm limiting the `$_GET` with `isnumeric()`, Without asking a too much complicated question I basically want that any other values than `id = 1` or `id = 2` would result in error how would one can achieve this in `PHP`? Do I have to use a function? if so what would be the right way to do so?

Comment: Only 1 or 2 or those are just examples?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 4):

You can make the accepted values dynamic (if 1 or 2 are just examples):

```php
$acceptedValues = [1, 2];

if(!in_array($_GET['id'], $acceptedValues)) {
    // send back error response here
    die();
}

// continue
```